# SQL Query: joining three tables to generate a Sales Report of Spend

Tags: sql

I normally work with MySQL so not sure how to get a query to work on SQL.

I have 3 tables:

**Table1**
ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL

This contains ORDER_LINE_NETT_TOTAL and also the ORDER_LINE_ORDER_ID

**Table 2**
ODBC_ORDER_ALL

This contains the ORDER_ID and also the ORDER_ACCOUNT_ID

**Table 3**
ODBC_ACCOUNT

This contains the ACCOUNT_ACCID and some other information on the account we may need in the future, hence why we are adding it.

I am joining table 1,2,3 together using the above constraints.

What I want to be able to do is generate a Sales Report of Spend showing Account Number and Total Spend but I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Any help much appreciated.

Here are the tables:

**ODBC_ORDER_LINE_ALL**

ORDER_LINE_ID
ORDER_LINE_ORDER_ID
ORDER_LINE_DATE
ORDER_LINE_MEDIACODE
ORDER_LINE_SOURCE
ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_ID
ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_CODE
ORDER_LINE_PRODUCT_NAME
ORDER_LINE_QUANTITY
ORDER_LINE_NETT_PRICE
ORDER_LINE_VAT_CODE
ORDER_LINE_VAT_RATE
ORDER_LINE_VAT
ORDER_LINE_NETT_TOTAL
ORDER_LINE_VAT_TOTAL
ORDER_LINE_GROSS_TOTAL
ORDER_LINE_UNIT_COST
ORDER_LINE_COST_CURRENCY
ORDER_LINE_COST_EXCHANGE_RATE
ORDER_LINE_TYPE
ORDER_LINE_STAGE
ORDER_LINE_STAGE_DATE
ORDER_LINE_INVOICE_ID
ORDER_LINE_INVOICE_DATE
ORDER_LINE_KIT_COMPONENT
ORDER_LINE_KIT_LINE_ID
ORDER_LINE_USER

**ODBC_ORDER_ALL**

ORDER_ID
ORDER_TYPE
ORDER_MEDIA_CODE_ID
ORDER_MEDIA_CODE
ORDER_MEDIA_SUBCODE
ORDER_TAKEN_BY
ORDER_DATE
ORDER_ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER_DELIVERY_ACCOUNT_ID
ORDER_SOURCE_ID
ORDER_SOURCE
ORDER_WEB_ORDER_ID
ORDER_MULTI_CLIENT_ID
ORDER_MULTI_CLIENT

**ODBC_ACCOUNT**

ACCOUNT_ACCID
ACCOUNT_ACC_TYPE
ACCOUNT_REF
ACCOUNT_TITLE
ACCOUNT_FORENAME
ACCOUNT_SURNAME
ACCOUNT_COMPANY_NAME
ACCOUNT_HOUSE_NAME
ACCOUNT_ADD1
ACCOUNT_ADD2
ACCOUNT_ADD3
ACCOUNT_ADD4
ACCOUNT_POSTCODE
ACCOUNT_COUNTRY
ACCOUNT_PHONE1
ACCOUNT_PHONE2
ACCOUNT_FAX1
ACCOUNT_FAX2
ACCOUNT_EMAIL
ACCOUNT_WEBSITE
ACCOUNT_PRICELIST_ID
ACCOUNT_MEDIACAMPAIGN_ID
ACCOUNT_CREATED_DATE

Comment: you told that you were not getting correct syntax..

just paste here your query..

means what you have done as of now

Comment: One problem is that it is very difficult to refer to anonymous tables.  I dunno what it is about SO and SQL questions, but it is a common trait that the table names are not given in the question, which always makes it much harder to give the answer!  I'm going to edit the question to give 'Table 2' the name ODBC_ORDER, and 'Table 3' the name ODBC_ACCOUNT - they look like plausible names given 'Table 1'.  But don't hesitate to fix the names if they're wrong.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: StackOverflow--Making comp.databases.* look sophisticated since 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the table names are 'Table 1' ODBC_Order_Line_All, 'Table 2' ODBC_Order_All, 'Table 3' ODBC_Account, then you simply need to join the three tables on the relevant joining columns, and sum the order line nett total entries for each account:

```
SELECT A.Account_AccID, SUM(L.Order_Line_Nett_Total) AS TotalSpend
  FROM ODBC_Account        AS A
  JOIN ODBC_Order_All      AS O ON A.Account_Acc_ID = O.Order_Account_ID
  JOIN ODBC_Order_Line_All AS L ON O.Order_ID = L.Order_Line_Order_ID
 GROUP BY A.Account_AccID;
```

However, while there is nothing but the Account_AccID selected from ODBC_Account, there is no actual need to select from the ODBC_Account table; you can join just the two tables, yielding a simpler query:

```
SELECT O.Order_Account_ID  AS Acount_AccID, SUM(L.Order_Line_Nett_Total) AS TotalSpend
  FROM ODBC_Order_All      AS O ON A.Account_Acc_ID = O.Order_Account_ID
  JOIN ODBC_Order_Line_All AS L ON O.Order_ID = L.Order_Line_Order_ID
 GROUP BY Account_AccID;
```

There is nothing here that is different in MySQL from any other SQL DBMS, so your knowledge of MySQL should transfer directly.